# Is there a condition check operator in js that returns the condition itself in the case of true?

Tags: javascript

I often declare several variables at the beginning of a function and want to write the result of the function execution into them, but before that, check whether the function returned the result

```
const a = myfuncA()
const b = myfuncB()
const c = myfuncC()
if(a){
  if(b){
    if(c){
     Code...
    }
    else{
      funcErr(c)
    }
  }
  else{
    funcErr(b)
  }
}else{
  funcErr(a)
}
```

Conditional operator "?" already allows you to shorten the code, but does not return the condition and the function must be executed 3 times

```
const a = (myfuncA()) ? myfuncA() : funcErr(myfuncA())
const b = (myfuncB()) ? myfuncB() : funcErr(myfuncB())
const c = (myfuncC()) ? myfuncC() : funcErr(myfuncC())
```

From the obvious, of course, I can write my own function to which I will pass the function under investigation and a callback for actions in case of an error

```
myIfFync(a,collback){
  if (a){
    return a
  }
  collback(a)
}
```

```
const a = myIfFunc(myfuncA(),funcErr)
const b = myIfFunc(myfuncB(),funcErr)
const c = myIfFunc(myfuncC(),funcErr)
```

It seems to me that js has a built-in method for these purposes, but I don’t know about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `&&` as follows.
If the result is truthy, the function will execute.

```js
const a = myfuncA()
const b = myfuncB()
const c = myfuncC()
a && funcErr(a)
b && funcErr(b)
c && funcErr(c)
```

Comment: Thank you, although your example did not suit me, because in case of failure, my function returned null and the && operator refused to execute funcErr, I just used the OR operator and this is what I needed

`const a = myfuncA() || funcErr(a) 
const b = myfuncB() || funcErr(b)
const c = myfuncC() || funcErr(c)`

It was so obvious...